# How do I stop music from playing in the background? (react-native-sound)

Tags: android, react-native

I am using the [react-native-sound](https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound/) module but when I start a sound and I press the `Home` button to get out of the app, the sound keeps playing.

When I reload the app, it starts the sound a second time and I can't use `.stop()` on it to destroy it because it only destroys the second one which was loaded on top of the first one.

How am I supposed to stop that?

```
class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props.actions.fetchScores();
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
   nextProps.music.backgroundMusic.stop()

   setInterval( () => { 
    nextProps.music.backgroundMusic.play()
    nextProps.music.backgroundMusic.setNumberOfLoops(-1)
   }, 1000);
  }
}

export default connect(store => ({
    music: store.music
  })
)(Home);
```

Comment: call `yourSound.stop()` in activities `onPause()` , `onStop()` or `onDestroy()` method..

Comment: The sound is the backgroundmusic of my app. It's called with mySound.play() in the `componentWillReceiveProps()` function on the first page. When reload the app it starts another background music on top of the previous one. The `stop()` function doesn't work anymore as if it can't detect it anymore. That's why I am trying to avoid resuming the song when I get out of the app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you should use [AppState](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate.html) to stop music when in background and enable when app state changes again.

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
},
componentWillUnmount: function() {
  AppState.removeEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
},
_handleAppStateChange: function(currentAppState) {
  if(currentAppState == "background") {
      stop();
  } 
  if(currentAppState == "active") {
      resume();
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

In react-ative-sound Library you Just need to add this line

```
if (global.sound) global.sound.stop();
```

You can add this in backhandler or componentWillUnmount.